# Packaged django apps installed from Pypi on new django project doesnt show the apps folders and files

Tags: django

In a former django project i have packaged an app for reusing it later in another django project.
The app was packaged in both formats, source (tar.gz) and wheel and uploaded to Test Pypi.
Then I have installed this app in a new project. Though the functionality of the app works... tested in the dev server, its files and folders are not shown in the VS Code editor, I would like to have them for editing purposes. Thanks in advance for help

Everything is already explained